# JSON items to have pages of their own

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contentful

I've started using contentful, created a few entries and now I want to make a simple dynamic page with subpages.

Basically, a portfolio. What i want to have there - index page with links to inner portfolio pages. I've got a JSON with entries each of them containing title, content, slug, id, etc.

How do i make them have each of their page with url? Template is going to be the same. So for example the user comes to url.com/someurl and he sees the page for some specific item in entries.

My gut is telling me that usually controller does this kind of job. Should i try using some frameworks like angularjs?

Comment: What are you using for the existing pages? (And why are you looking at client side solutions instead of server side solutions?)

Comment: I'm much more comfortable with js than with php because i don't have back end development experience. 

For now there's only plain html, javascript and jQuery, not using any CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this simple example app I've been working on, using just plain JS. It's not entirely finished but showcases the very basic principles of using Contentful to build a frontend only app with the [contentful.js SDK](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js): https://github.com/contentful/product-catalogue-js

Give that you added an angularjs tag I'm assuming you could also be interested in this: https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-contentful

Essentially you should just build an app as any other, using whatever framework (or not) you want, but get the data from Contentful instead of an AJAX endpoint or any other data library.

What you might want to think of as well is how you structure your Entries and Content Types in Contentful. A good strategy is to have some kind of Entry that corresponds to a page (for instance, in that example app there are Products and there are individual pages for each Product), and then have related Entries you can link to it (like say, Blog Posts and Images).